# Function to remove set of trailing characters from string

Tags: algorithm, strings, c99

I needed the ability to truncate the trailing end of path strings in a routine that builds new search paths as it recursively searches directories. After not finding what I was looking for I created function below.

Expected behavior is that function `remove_trailing_chars()` will update `in` to remove any occurrences of chars contained in `rem`, *iff* they exist contiguously at the very end of the original version of `in`.

Once a character in the `in` string becomes *the trailing char* and it is not included in `rem`, then function updates `in` with latest version and returns.

it has been tested for several variations of input `char` arrays `in` and `rem`, including these.

```
    char in[] = "this is a string with \\ *\\*";//edit this string as needed to test
    char rem[] = "\\* ";//edit this string as needed to test
```

results in `"this is a string with"` without following space

```
    char in[] = "this is a string with *\\*";//edit this string as needed to test
    char rem[] = "\\*";//edit this string as needed to test
```

results in `"this is a string with "` includes following space

I am interested in suggestions for efficiency improvements in speed, and readability improvements.  (suggestions on more idiomatic methods are welcome.) I do not believe memory should be an issue with this for my usage, but if there are thoughts on any pitfalls in that area, please include them as well.

Here is the code, including one usage case...  (Compiler command line and its disassembly are included further down as well.)

```
#include <stdbool.h>//bool
#include <string.h>//strlen, strcpy
#include <stdlib.h>

//prototypes
void remove_trailing_chars(char *in, const char *rem);

/// demonstrate removing all chars in 'rem' if trailing in 'in'.
int main(void)
{
    char in[] = "this is a string with \\ *\\*";//edit this string as needed to test
    char rem[] = "\\* ";//edit this string as needed to test
    
    remove_trailing_chars(in, rem);
    
    return 0;
}
/// remove all occurrences of chars in 'rem' from end of 'in'
void remove_trailing_chars(char *in, const char *rem)
{
    bool found = true;//when false, last char of 'in' found no matches in 'rem'
    int len = strlen(in);
    char in_dup[len+1];
    strcpy(in_dup, in);
    
    while(found)
    {
        found = false;//for this element of rem
        len = strlen(in_dup);
        int i = 0;
        while(rem[i])
        {
            if(in_dup[len-1] == rem[i])
            {
                in_dup[len - 1] = 0;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;      
            }
        }
    }   
    strcpy(in, in_dup);
}
```

Using GCC, build was done with:

Release target:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -g  -c C:\tempExtract\remove_trainling_chars\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o
```

Debug target:  (to allow viewing disassembly)

```
gcc.exe -Wall -g -Wall -std=c99 -g  -c C:\tempExtract\remove_trainling_chars\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Accessing array out of bounds

The code here may try access `in_dup[-1]` in some cases:

> ```
> len = strlen(in_dup);
> int i = 0;
> while(rem[i])
> {
>     if(in_dup[len-1] == rem[i])
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

That is, when the input string is empty, or when the entire input string is made of characters in `rem`, then `in_dup` will become empty, `len` becomes 0, and `len - 1` will be an illegal access on `in_dup`.

In short, the code is missing a check on reaching the beginning of the input.

#### Avoid unnecessary copying

The code copies `in` to `in_dup`, works with `in_dup`, then copies back from it to `in`. This is unnecessary, you could work directly with `in`.

#### Avoid unnecessary computations

`len = strlen(in_dup)` is executed every time after some characters are removed from the end. This is inefficient, because `strlen` needs to loop over the entire string. Instead, you could count the number of characters removed, and then you'll know exactly the end of the input string.

#### Simplify algorithm

Consider this simpler algorithm:

- Loop from the end of the input, going backwards, until the beginning
- Loop over the characters in `rem`, check if it matches the last character of the input

  - If there is a match, delete the last character and break out of this inner loop
  - If there is no match, then we're done, break out of the outer loop

Implementation, including the other tips above applied as well:

```
void remove_trailing_chars(char *in, const char *rem)
{
    int remLength = strlen(rem);

    for (int i = strlen(in) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < remLength) {
            if (in[i] == rem[j]) {
                in[i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if (j == remLength) break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the detail in your explanations, and follow most of them.  I am unclear on your use of `strlen` in the `for` expression though.  i.e. you had made the point earlier about removing `strlen` from being called repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: @ryyker the initializer of the loop is only executed once ;-)

Answer (score 1):

- Recomputing of `strlen(in_dup)` at each iteration of the `while` loop drive the time complexity to quadratic. Better compute it once, and subtract 1 per iteration.
- I see no reason to copy `in` to `in_dup`, and then back. The second copy assumes that `in` is writable. Better operate directly on `in`.
- Use standard library. `strchr` does precisely the same job as the inner loop, and likely does it better.
- A variable like `bool found` is usually a red flag.

All that said, consider

```
char * end = in + strlen(in);
while (end > in) {
    char ch = *--end;
    if (strchr(rem, ch) {
        *end = 0;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great list of suggestions. All good except one question: Why does `bool found` usually indicate a _red flag_? btw, suggested code segment has one small typo: `(strchr(rem, ch)` -> `(strchr(rem, ch))`. Other than that, very clean. Thank you for reviewing.